# Erro ao acessar banco RDS com Heidsql

Tags: mysql, amazon-aws

recebo uma mensagem de erro ao entrar no banco RDS da Amazon:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os dados de acesso estão corretos
e o banco esta rodando.
Existe algum procedimento a ser feito para ter acesso ao banco RSD no Heidsql ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta consegui nesta postagem: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212945/aws-cant-connect-to-rds-database-from-my-machine

Vou traduzir por aqui:

1 - Ir até EC2 Dashboard

2 - Clicar em Security Groups tab

3 - Selecione apenas o grupo de segurança do banco de dados do RDS. Você verá os detalhes do grupo de segurança na parte inferior

4 - Clicar Inbound tab

5 - Clicar Edit button

6 - Adicionar Type:MYSQL/Aurora;Protocol:TCP;Range:3306;Source:0.0.0.0/0

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Note que esse procedimento permite que qualquer origem (0.0.0.0/0) conecte no seu banco, pode ser um problema de segurança.

Comment: Fato, como poderei corrigir isso ?

Comment: se eu substituir esse valor para ip de minha máquina posso corrigir este problema ?

Comment: Sim, ou de uma faixa de rede que confias, idealmente sobre TLS.